# Semantic Ontology for .NET Type System

Tags: .net, clr, rdf, semantic-web, owl

Is there an existing semantic ontology schema for representing relationships in the .NET / CLR type system?  I could see such a thing being implemented in RDF, OWL or even XSD, but have not been able to find anything.

If such a thing does exist, then where is the document located?

If it does not exist, then what is the recommended approach for representing .NET/CLR metadata in such a way that it can be integrated with unrelated semantic ontologies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any .NET-specific ontology, but there's [SCRO](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~alnusair/compre/scro.html), which is quite good as a starting point. I suggest you to take it and extend whenever something is missing.

Comment: the language agnostic approach is even more useful than what I was hoping for.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one specific to CLR/.Net but if you wanted something to start from you might want to look at the [Java Ontology](http://simile.mit.edu/2004/09/ontologies/java) which comes from a now defunct MIT project.

It's a pretty trivial ontology and you may want a lot more detail depending on exactly what metadata you were intending to represent.